# ASP.NET unable to access new field in Roles table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have just extended my AspNetRoles table like this:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public String ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public AspNetApplications Application { get; set; }
}
```

When I added my migration and updated the database, the ApplicationId and a discriminator column appeared.

However, when I need to access the data from this table, I cannot seem to access the new field:

```
List<ApplicationRole> data = (from ar in dbContext.Roles
     join a in dbContext.AspNetApplications
     on ar.ApplicationId equals a.Id
     select new ApplicationRole
     {
         Id = ar.Id,
         Name = ar.Name
         ApplicationId = (Unable to access this section)
     }).ToList();
```

I have tried following this tutorial http://johnatten.com/2014/06/22/asp-net-identity-2-0-customizing-users-and-roles/#Extending-Identity-Role and I have added a new ApplicationRoleManager in my IdentityConfig

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> roleStore): base(roleStore)
        {
        }
        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        }
    }
```

When I Seed my database, the ApplicationId gets filled up no problem. Only when I try to get data from it is when I get into issues.

Comment: Are stuck in this? Few days back u ask regarding this.

Comment: Yeah I tried redoing it using a new tutorial but im still stuck. I can't find many examples online.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds silly, but can you check if you did already define the ApplicationRole class in another namespace, maybe the one that you want to fill is from another namespace in which you have not defined ApplicationId

```
select new ApplicationRole
 {
     Id = ar.Id,
     Name = ar.Name , //or maybe because you do not have a comma after ar.Name
     ApplicationId = (Unable to access this section)
 }).ToList();
```